# Align bottom of view with centre of parent

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a CoordinatorLayout with a LinearLayout that contains other views inside it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Last Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The above code aligns the center of LinearLayout with the center of CoordinatorLayout.

I want to align the bottom of the last button with the center of CoordinatorLayout.

*I use the CoordinatorLayout because there is a bottomsheet RecyclerView as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be a trick, but it should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/hiddenGuidelineView"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 2"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Last Button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/hiddenGuidelineView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```